# is weblogic-maven-plugin available from maven center repository?

Tags: maven, weblogic

When i run my maven build script i get

```
Plugin com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:2.9.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:jar:2.9.1: Could not find artifact com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:pom:2.9.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

But when i search in repository i can see it there http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|weblogic-maven-plugin
Why this plugin is not available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Oracle WebLogic is not an open source product, Oracle has decided not to publish their Maven plugins in the Maven Central repository (providing the sources for each published artifact has now become a requirement, according to the [Maven Central Repository Usage Guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)).

Until recently, the only way was to build and install the WebLogic JAR file into the local Maven cache.

Starting from 2015, Oracle has set up a Maven repository which can be accessed by anyone having a valid OTN account - see abarisone's answer.

Comment: this answer is no longer valid. please check @abarisone answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

From the early months of 2015 Oracle has at last made its Maven repository available for Continuous Integration purposes.

This means that you will be able to find not only all Oracle Database artifacts but also those related to Fusion Middleware, Oracle Service Bus, ADF and so on.
You can find more info reading [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_server_and_the_oracle).

Obviously you need to have a valid OTN account to log in, and the same is required to configure maven proxies and Nexus.

Once registered you will have access to the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010) which explains all the instructions in order to configure the repository.

About Sonatype Nexus, you need at least version 2.11.2 to be able to add the Oracle repository, as reported [here](https://redstack.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/nexus-and-atifactory-support-for-proxying-oracle-maven-repository/)