# maven weblogic security jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, weblogic11g

I am working on an existing application which has below reference inside the code.

```
import weblogic.security.providers.authentication.UserNameMapper;
```

The exising application has weblogic.jar as dependency, but from weblogic 10 onwards, weblogic.jar has been split into multiple jars and currently com.bea.core.common.security.providers.env_1.0.0.0_6-2-0-0 in Weblogic 10.3.6 has UserNameMapper.java.

My question is where to find the maven definition for this jar? If not, what is the alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle might have pulled the jar out of Maven.

Refer here - [is weblogic-maven-plugin available from maven center repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296213/is-weblogic-maven-plugin-available-from-maven-center-repository)

Alternate solution:

Either you can include that jar in your classpath of application, or you can install particular jar file in your maven reopos.

Refer here - [build maven project with propriatery libraries included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491199/build-maven-project-with-propriatery-libraries-included/4491343#4491343)